# Pygame Использования игровых монет

Tags: python, pygame

Создаю игры на Python/Pygame. Вся логика игры практически готова, за исключением одного очень важного элемента, к которой я никак не могу подступиться. Документация по Pygame-у не помогла. Подходящего решения в интернете я также не нашел. Поэтому обращаюсь сюда и буду рад любым подсказкам. Итак идея:

В игре существуют игровые монеты "coin". Это обычная игра платформер. Пользователь игры собирает эти монеты. Нужно внедрить их использование. У меня есть две кнопки. Кнопка номер 1 - "Обычный уровень". Нажатие этой кнопки вызывает начало игры и не требует использования монет. Кнопка номер 2 - "Продвинутый уровень". В данный момент эта кнопка тоже вызывает начала игры и не требует монет. Но мне нужно сделать эту кнопку не активной и при нажатии на нее необходимо чтобы игра запросила у пользователя определенное количество монет и в случае если игрок согласится, то потратив единожды указанное количество монет, игрок сможет активировать эту кнопку навсегда. Кто нибудь может помочь мне реализовать эту идею через pygame? Буду рад любым подсказкам/помощи и т.д. Спасибо.

Comment: создайте файл, в котором будет хранится информация куплен уровень или нет. При запуске игры считывает файл и проверяйте это значение. А при покупке замените значение в файле

Comment: Спасибо за отклик @Danis Но моя проблема вовсе не в этом. Возможно я не так подробно описал проблему с которой столкнулся. За что прошу извинить. Я не знаю как реализовать саму логику. В данный момент я нажимаю на обе кнопки и игра начинается. Когда я пытаюсь создать дополнительные кнопки типа "Купить" или "Отмена", то ничего не происходит. Для тестирования своего кода я создал кнопку "ТЕСТ", но она только мигает и исчезает с экрана. Исходя из этого я думаю что я не на правильном пути поэтому и не опубликовал свой код. Если нужно могу опубликовать ту часть кода где я застрял.